# Newly created Analytics properties do not register hits (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This is going to drive me nuts.

I set up a new property to track an iOS app, and started setting up the GA client SDK on the client app. However, the property dashboard does not register any hits from my app.

I get this console output when sending hit:

```
(GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:431): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_u" = ".ooKo9L";
        "&_v" = "mi3.0.9";
        "&a" = 1865856373;
        "&aid" = "com.XXX.XX";
        "&an" = XX;
        "&ate" = "<null>";
        "&av" = "0.9.71a";
        "&cd" = "SCREEN NAME";
        "&cid" = "549985f5-53de-44f7-8ddf-39f8ecc4bf79";
        "&idfa" = "<null>";
        "&sr" = 320x568;
        "&t" = screenview;
        "&tid" = "UA-XXXX-X";
        "&ul" = en;
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 18323534810575848962;
        gaiVersion = "3.09";
    };
    timestamp = "2014-10-23 12:48:47 +0000";
}
```

And I even get the following console output at times of dispatch:

```
GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:195): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect
GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatchWithCompletionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:536): Sending hit(s) GET: https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?av=0.9.71a&a=1865856373&cd=Akustikhane+CUSTOM&t=screenview&_crc=0&ul=en&cid=549985f5-53de-44f7-8ddf-39f8ecc4bf79&tid=UA-XXXX-X&_u=.ooKo9L&sr=320x568&v=1&aid=com.XXX.XX&an=XX&_v=mi3.0.9&ht=1414068527552&qt=5882&z=18323534810575848962
GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:completionHandler:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:161): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:443): hit(s) Successfully dispatched
GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:sendMore:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:174): 1 hit(s) sent
```

...which pretty much tells me that there is nothing wrong with the client-side. I checked the account ID I use a thousand times and it is correct.

The code I use to send hits is as follows for additional info:

```
//Initialization
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 10;
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-X"];

//Sending hit
[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] set:kGAIScreenName value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ CUSTOM", view]];
[[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView]  build]];
```

The weirdest part is that **when I set the account ID to an older GA property of mine, the same code REGISTERS HITS on the property dashboard without any problems.** But NOT for the new property. I created the new property in the exact same way as the old one. (It's set for mobile, and belongs to the same account) So I can't see any reason for it to fail. There doesn't seem to be any problems with the view associated with it either.

This is all I see:

[image]

Have you encountered anything like this before? Can my property be set up in an incorrect way somehow? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something that gets me every time - by default the GA dashboard is set to show events from some date to yesterday. Would you check if you've set it so that it'll show events from today as well? You can check that in the upper right corner on the calendar input. https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3zqq79ng19qem2/Screenshot%202014-10-23%2016.40.04.png?dl=0 - (doesn't include today by default)

Comment: OH MY GOD THANKS. I cannot believe I spent 5 hours and a good portion of my sanity for something this stupid. I was only checking the "real time" pane, which for some reason wasn't being updated also due to date restrictions. By the way why not post this as an answer and let me upvote you to eternity?

Comment: I've added it as an answer, so that hopefully people would have an easier time finding it. I've also wasted countless hours on numerous occasions, because I forget about it every time, lol. I've seen people say that it takes a day for these to show up and this is where that notion comes from.

Comment: Did "real time" start updating once you'd changed these settings too? I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Have faced exact same scenario... and figured out that it will take some time to receive the events from app for newly created property ID. (In my case its after 2 hours.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that gets me every time - by default the GA dashboard is set to show events from some date to yesterday. Would you check if you've set it so that it'll show events from today as well?

You can check that in the upper right corner on the calendar input.

[image]

As you can see it doesn't include today by default.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, while the above works correctly for me too, Realtime tracking still doesn't show any hits. However, it DOES show in Realtime for an older property. I think this is a bug in Google Analytics,  not our code.

Comment: It's driving me mad. I genuinely think their system must be having issues at the moment rather than it being a programming error or an analytics profile mistake. I've set GA up tens of times - this is the first time it's been cocking up.